# Make fields non editable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set a div as non editable  with its id or class using jQuery or JavaScript after submission?

```
$('#id').attr("disabled",true);
```

is not working for a div.

Comment: `divs` are not editable anyway... you have to explain your problem better.

Comment: Are u using contentEditable div or u want to disable controls inside div?

Comment: Only form controls (INPUT and similar) have a 'disabled' property. You seem to be trying to apply it to a DIV.

Comment: div are not editable...are you using any plugin?

Comment: Felix Kling, right now I am working on struts, I have two text fields, three checkboxes, two radio buttons inside a div. After getting the responce i hav to display responce in the same page, but i need to make them(two text fields, three....) as non editable. For this i have to use javascript or jquery. Can u please tel me the solution.

Comment: @vissupepala: @Maurice gave the right answer then.

Comment: @Felix Kling, I tried like "$("#field1,#field2,#box1").attr("disabled",true);" this mannor. but it also not working.

Comment: @vissupepala: There must be something else wrong in your script. This clearly works: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/EZtrq/

Comment: @Felix Kling, I got it. I tried by giving same class name for all individual fields. something like                                       <input type = "text" class="AuthBox4">                                <input type = "checkbox" class="AuthBox4">                         <input type = "radio" class="AuthBox4"> and tried to disable by using following and finally i got the solution. $('.AuthBox4').attr("disabled",true); thanks to every one by giving your most valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little bit confusing, but here's an example of what I believe you wish to happen: http://jsbin.com/uwata4

Comment: I have to set for some fields not for one field

Comment: You can just add the class 'disabled' to any field which you wish to.

Comment: sorry for late. it is the exact answer what i am expecting. i got it. thanks alot. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
$("#id input,#id textarea, #id select").attr("disabled",true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean all form elements WITHIN your div? if so:

```
$("#id").children("input, select, textarea").attr("disabled",true);
```